# Coordinate transformation and partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

Let $u(t,x)$ be a function in the coordinates $t$ and $x$. Now $u$ is to be expressed in coordinates $t$ and $\xi$ instead where $\xi=x-ct$.

Do we then have 
$$
u_{xx}=u_{\xi\xi}+cu_{\xi}?
$$

I tried to answer this but did not come along. Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to have different names for different things. If you write
$$
U(t, \xi) = u(t, \xi  + ct)
$$
then you can compute
\begin{align}
U_{\xi}(t, \xi) 
&= u_x(t, \xi + ct) \cdot \frac{d(\xi + ct)}{d\xi}  \\
&= u_x(t, \xi + ct)  
\end{align}
and similarly, 
\begin{align}
U_{\xi\xi}(t, \xi) &= u_{xx}(t, \xi + ct).
\end{align}

Post-comment addition:

On the other hand, if you compute $U_t$, you get

\begin{align}
U_{t}(t, \xi) 
&= u_t(t, \xi + ct) \cdot \frac{d(t)}{dt} + u_x(t, \xi + ct) \cdot \frac{d(\xi + ct)}{dt}  \\
&= u_t(t, \xi + ct)  + u_x(t, \xi + ct) c  \\
\end{align}
so that 
\begin{align}
u_t(t, \xi + ct) &= U_{t}(t, \xi) - u_x(t, \xi + ct) c
\end{align}
And since $u_x = U_{\xi}$ (modulo shuffling arguments a little), this can be rewritten
\begin{align}
u_t(t, \xi + ct) &= U_{t}(t, \xi) - c ~U_{\xi}(t, \xi)
\end{align}

Comment: I am just wondering about the following. The original PDE, i.e. in coordinates $t$ and $x$ is given by $u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)-w$, Now, after going over to coordinates $t$ and $\xi=x-ct$, the ODE is stated to be $u_t=u_{\xi\xi}+ cu_{\xi}+f(u)-w$. And I am wondering where the $cu_{\xi}$ comes from.

Comment: See "post-comment additions" above. Once you substitute in the expression for $u_{xx}$ and $u_{t}$ into the original PDE, you'll get a new PDE for the function $U$ that'll look like $U_t = U_{\xi\xi} + cU_{\xi} + F(U) - w$, where $F(U(t, \xi))$ is defined to be $f(u(t, x))$, using the coordinate transformation above. Calling "f" and "F" by the same name, and calling $u$ and $U$ by the same name...that's typical (alas), and has confused generations of students.

Comment: Ah, thats the multi-dimensional chain rule that you use to compute $U_t(t,\xi)$.

Comment: Exactly right. $~$